# How to extract a substring from a text file?

Tags: powershell

I have the following text file

```
testA=foo
testB=foobar
testC=Whatever
```

Now I want to extract the value for `testB` which is `foobar`. With my current PowerShell command I can only receive the whole line:

```
testB=foobar
```

My command is:

```
Select-String -Path .\test.txt -Pattern "testB=" -List
```

I could see that there is replace function for strings, so that you could replace `testB=` with empty string, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *don't have to replace anything* to capture the value. Instead, add a *capture group* to your search pattern. Then you are able to access the captured value:

```
(Select-String -Path $scripts.tmp -Pattern "testB=(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Ah, ok. How can I additionally trim the value?

Comment: Just add `.Trim()` after `.Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Should be .Matches[0].Groups instead .Matches.Groups

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Content | where {$_ -like "testB*"}).Replace('testB=','')
```

Comment: ops, sorry, typo ;(

Answer (score 1):

You can use Substring, for example:

```
$line = 'testB=foobar'
$res = $line.Substring($line.IndexOf('=')+1)
```